# When using a recursive mapping, why is there no infinite recursion when RHS starts with LHS?

Tags: key-bindings

I noticed that the following mapping does not cause an infinite recursion (when pressing `x`).

```
:map x x
```

I didn't see anything in Vim's documentation that would explain this.

Further experimentation seems to suggest that when the right-hand-side of a mapping starts with the left-hand-side, there is no infinite recursion. For example, `:map x Xx` causes infinite recursion, but `:map x xX` doesn't (when pressing `x`).

My expectation is that when the contents of the left-hand-side are included on the right-hand-side, this would result in an infinite recursion, regardless of the positioning within the right-hand-side.

Is there some documented reason for the behavior I'm observing (e.g., special handling if the beginning of the right-hand-side matches the left-hand-side)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is documented in [`:help recursive_mapping`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#recursive_mapping):

> There is one exception: If the `{rhs}` starts with `{lhs}`, the first character is not mapped again (this is Vi compatible).
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> :map ab abcd
> ```
>
> will execute the `a` command and insert "bcd" in the text.  The `ab` in the `{rhs}` will not be mapped again.

Answer (score 0):

Normally vim prevent a mapping to go crazy by limiting the maximum number of recursion. You can set the value of the maxmapdepth option (see `:help maxmapdepth`):

```
                                                'maxmapdepth' 'mmd' E223
'maxmapdepth' 'mmd'     number  (default 1000)
                        global
        Maximum number of times a mapping is done without resulting in a
        character to be used.  This normally catches endless mappings, like
        ":map x y" with ":map y x".  It still does not catch ":map g wg",
        because the 'w' is used before the next mapping is done.  See also
        key-mapping.
```

Comment: It appears that `maxmapdepth` is not related to `:map x xX` not having an infinite recursion. For other scenarios where the `maxmapdepth` is reached, I receive an error message, `E223: recursive mapping`. However, I do not receive that for the `:map x xX` mapping (when pressing `x`). Also, setting `maxmapdepth` to its largest value, `9223372036854775807`, does not impact the responsiveness of pressing `x` (the UI would freeze if the mapping were expanded that many times).

Comment: hmm, this is strange and really interesting. I didn't noticed this kind of behaviour. It would be cool to find an explanation about this problem